# integrate facebook with my current login system mobile app spoofing?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I have had a mobile app for some time now which uses a custom login flow that utilizes json web tokens (Java based front end servers). I would now like to be able to allow users to login via Facebook for convenience reasons. Reading the flow of Facebook login the user enters their FB credentials, then Facebook returns back to the device (if successful of course) an access token alongside other information such as email, scope etc. When this information comes back to the device I would then send to my server the email address and check if it is a current user or not. If it is I would allow them to proceed , but if they are new they would then need to add some additional information. The problem I am seeing is can't the user just spoof the email address on the client side before sending it my server? How do I know the email coming into my app is for the user validated for me.

I have read their documentation on integrating FB with existing login systems (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers but can't seem to find ) and android/iOS logins but can't find how this common scenario is prevented.

Comment: Don’t send the email address then – send the access token, and make the request for their data (including email address) server-side. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4#confirm, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security

Comment: And I hope you are aware that you will not _get_ an email address for every Facebook user.

Comment: @CBroe Okay so I just read your link it is a an endpoint I need to call by HTTP request. Thanks so much. If you create an answer I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I am seeing is can't the user just spoof the email address on the client side before sending it my server?

Don’t send the email address then – send the access token, and make the request for their data (including email address) server-side.

Facebook has a bunch of resources dealing with such security concerns in their documentation. Check f.e. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4#confirm and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security